# Finding the actual extents of a ListBoxItem with UserControl as content

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm trying to find the extents of a UI element in a ListBox. I use WPF / c# for this.
The code is roughly as follows:

```
ObservableCollection<SomeUserControl> TheCollection = new ObservableCollection<SomeUserControl>();
// setup
ListBox lb = new ListBox();
// code omitted here that setup the listbox with 2 columns
lb.ItemsSource = TheCollection;
// code omitted here that populates TheCollection with UI elements
```

Then I register a mouse event and I would like to know when a specific point is bounded by a specific element in the listbox. For this I have the following means to do it:

```
UIElement GetObjectHit(Point P) {
  if (!lb.IsVisible) return null;
  foreach(var i in TheCollection) {
    FrameworkElement item = i as FrameworkElement;
    if (item == null || !item.IsVisible)
      continue;
    Point P00 = item.TranslatePoint(new Point(0,0), lb);
    Point P11 = item.TranslatePoint(new Point(item.ActualWidth, item.ActualHeight), lb);
    if (IsBounded(P, P00, P11)
      return item;
  }
  return null;
}

UIElement GetObjectHit(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
  return GetObjectHit(e.GetPosition(lb));
}
```

This works great with one exception...
The different user controls I have have varying sizes and the ListBox will then extend each item to the maximum element size currently in list and then center the smaller UserControls that are in the list.

So what's the problem?
Well when the position is in the white area which is inside the ListBoxItem area but outside the UserControl area the code above fails to find the intersection.

So my question is as follows:
Do I have to do a separate loop first to get the maximum extends of each UI element or is there any way to get the current extent of the ListBoxItem in the ListBox (even though the UserControl extent is smaller)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the unlikely event if anyone needs the answer to this I managed to get this to work as follows:

```
UIElement GetObjectHit(Point P) {
  if (!lb.IsVisible) return null;
  foreach(var i in TheCollection) {
    var item = i as SomeUserControl;
    ListBoxItem lbi = lb.ContainerFromElement(item) as ListBoxItem;
    if (lbi == null || !lbi.IsVisible)
      continue;
    Point P00 = lbi.TranslatePoint(new Point(0,0), lb);
    Point P11 = lbi.TranslatePoint(new Point(lbi.ActualWidth, lbi.ActualHeight), lb);
    if (IsBounded(P, P00, P11)
      return i;
  }
  return null;
}
```